# regex java, unable to get the value

Tags: java

Consider a String variable `pri` with value `07:45:32PM` , now in order to obtain the `PM` alone I applied,

```
pri = pri.replaceAll("[^A-Z]","");
```

So far things work fine, but trying to compare the value in the variable does not work, ie :

```
   if(pri=="PM")
   {
        hh+=12;

   }
```

The body of the loop does not get executed. My question is are the two values different, ie `Pri=="PM"` , Why is it so? And how do I get to check my if loop in a precise way? Thank you

**EDIT1**

So I tried `if(pri.equals("PM"))` instead of `if(pri=="PM")` , but still it did **not** solve the problem!

Comment: use pri.equals("PM")

Comment: Your code with that input works as expected for me when using `equals`. You must be doing something different which you haven't shown.

Comment: For your actual problem, did you consider using something like [`new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ssaa").parse(pri)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: Show your complete code (getting date string, replaceAll, comparing). Dump the value of pri, it might not be "PM" as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Use "equalsIgnoreCase()" method for comparing strings.

```
   if(pri.equalsIgnoreCase("PM"))
  {
    hh+=12;

   }
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code: a missing `)` bracket at the end of the if clause

Comment: @Phate01, You're right, good catch thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but why didnt just `pri.equals("PM")` work?

Comment: You can be more sure if you ignore the string case; in this situation it would have worked anyway

Comment: @Perdomoff you're welocme buddy

Comment: @oblivion, Because  if pri is "pm", the equals() will return false, but equalsIgnoreCase() will return true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.equals` not `==` to compare two `String` Object.

```
    if(pri.equals("PM"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(pri.equals("PM"))` instead.